# Android: Saved Instance State with VideoView

Tags: android

Am trying to play videos which i have in my sd card and i want to make video resume after any action happens like receive call
so what can i do??
i do this code but can't save current path for video

i can't save the path
                package net.ovtraining.firsttask;

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.media.MediaPlayer;
        import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.MediaController;
        import android.widget.VideoView;

        public class PlayVideo extends Activity {

            private VideoView video_view;
            private String[] fileName = {
                    "google1.webm", "google2.webm", "google3.webm",
                    "google4.webm", "google5.webm", "google6.webm"};
            private List<String> paths;

            private int mCurrentPosition = -1;
            int mCurrentPath;

            private int count = 0;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                video_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

                String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("videos").getAbsolutePath()+"/";
                paths = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < fileName.length; i++) {
                    paths.add(baseDir + fileName[i]);
                }

                Log.i("path", baseDir);

                if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                    mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(Constants.CURRENT_POSITION);
                }

                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(video_view);
                video_view.setMediaController(mediaController);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                play();
                video_view.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play();
                    }
                });
                super.onStart();
            }

            public void play() {
                if(count < paths.size()) {
                    video_view.stopPlayback();
                    video_view.setVideoPath(paths.get(count));
                    Log.i("TAG", paths.get(count));
                    video_view.requestFocus();
                    video_view.start();
                    if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
                        video_view.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                mCurrentPosition = video_view.getCurrentPosition();
                super.onPause();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                outState.putInt(Constants.CURRENT_PATH, mCurrentPath);
                outState.putInt(Constants.CURRENT_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm looking into it. Some have suggested I use a `Fragment` retainer to save the instance of my video `Uri` file, but haven't been able to get it to work so far. Still working on it.

Comment: Yes, the solution was Override Activity onRestart() method like this.
@Override
 protected void onRestart() {
  count--;
  play();
  super.onRestart();
 }. Hope this help